# Unable to launch the node with admin access on Windows

Tags: ros2, windows, launch

My setup:

- Windows 11
- ROS2 IRON patch release 3
- VS studio 2019

When I execute the launch file on the terminal with admin access, it hangs and shows the following info:

```
C:\dev\radar_IRON_ws>ros2 launch radar_visualization radar_launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\yernar.kubegenov\.ros\log\2024-01-19-09-04-52-503327-DE03-OF-WL0094-31608
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [radar_visualization_node.EXE-1]: process started with pid [8196]
[INFO] [rviz2.EXE-2]: process started with pid [3304]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher.EXE-3]: process started with pid [25648]
[INFO] [rqt-4]: process started with pid [27396]
```

But, it works on the normal terminal. What could be the reasons behind it?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Not exactly sure but this may help: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/543

Comment: I have recently changed to new laptop, but still same setup (Windows 11 & Ros2 Iron). I dont have this issue anymore. Anyway, its good keep in mind.

Comment: Glad that issue no longer exists.

Comment: I got one important insight, it is Visual Studio related error/bug/blockage. So, if you are facing the same problem just run your application on normal command prompt.